# Get list of current schema validation errors from Monaco with JSON schema

Tags: monaco-editor

I have a Monaco editor setup similar to the example one on the playground: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults

I would like to get a list of the current schema validation warnings so I can show them to the user in a list in my UI.  (ie. get a list of all the locations and the text similar to what you see when you hover over the highlighted warnings in the example above).

Is there an API with Monaco to get a list of all the current validation errors/warnings?

Comment: I think `Monaco.editor.getModelMarkers()` should return that information. All you need to do is figure out what the owner of these markers is. In your case, it might be "json", so `Monaco.editor.getModelMarkers({owner: "json")` would return the information you look for. Please let me know if this works, so I can do a proper answer to your question :-)

Comment: @AstorBizard That seems to do it.  I am pretty surprised as I expected something like a problem service or something to get access to all these things instead of accessing the "markers" on the editor.  But as long as it works, I am good to go.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, validation errors and warnings in Monaco editor are stored as [IMarker](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IMarker.html)s.
To get a list of these markers, there is a method [getModelMarkers()](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#getModelMarkers), that returns the list of all markers from a given **owner**.
Usually, for validation errors and warnings from a language, the owner is the id of the said language, `"json"` in your case.

So, to get validation errors and warnings from JSON schema, this will get the job done:

```js
var markers = Monaco.editor.getModelMarkers({owner: "json"});
```